# Using GetTickCount for "loop"

Tags: c

Hi When my application start I load a function - call a function which name is CreateFileNow(){}

I want to make a loop, but i dont know how. I want to write data in every 15 sec. So I call the function when application start, write data into the file, than wait 15 sec and write again data into the file.

```
FILE* file;

    if (fopen_s(&file, "Accesslog.txt", "w") != 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    fprintf(file, "Test");

    fclose(file);
```

How can I make a loop which run this code part in every 15 sec?
I dont want to use While and Sleep, Somebody can help to make it with GetTickcount();?

Comment: Which programming language are you using, of the two you have tagged?

Comment: Sorry I didnt removed the another one.

Answer (score 0):

By the use of `fopen_s` I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio.  So you can use the `Sleep` function:

```
while(/* some condition */) {
    Sleep(15000);
    fprintf(file, "Test");
}
```

Comment: `fopen_s` is optional standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1

Comment: Sleep is not good for me, because if its Sleep the app its not working correctly. Its a game client, so I cannot sleep it.. I need to make it work by using the Tick coint, I need to put the tickcount when the client start in a variable, than check the tickcount is bigger than the variable value, if yes write into the file, else set the new tickcount into the variable and start from the begin, I just dont know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `thread` that does timing part for you. The thread will not interfere with your main program. The global variable updates every 15 seconds and triggers the `main thread` to update values into file.

```
#include <pthread.h>

int update_file = 0;

void *time_thread(void *arg)
{
    while (1) {
    sleep(15);
    update_file = 1;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &time_thread, NULL);
    while (1) {
    while (update_file == 0);
    FILE *file;
        if (fopen_s(&file, "Accesslog.txt", "w") != 0) {
            return;
        }
    fprintf(file, "Test");
    fclose(file);
    update_file = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not working. If I make this my application doesnt open.. I call the CreateFileNow(){} function when the app start and than I want to call it in every 15 sec.. with the sleep its just sleep, and not opening. Thats why I asked to make it work with GetTickCount();. While is not good for me.